# Backbone.js and FormData

Tags: javascript, json, html, backbone.js, form-data

Is there any way using Backbone.js and it's model architecture that I can send a formdata object to the server? The problem I'm running into is that everything Backbone sends is encoded as JSON so the formdata object is not properly sent (obviously).

I'm temporarily working around this by making a straight jQuery ajax request and including the formdata object as the data property, but this is less than ideal.

Comment: You can override [`sync`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) globally, per-model, or per-collection to talk to the server any way you want.

Comment: Hey, your suggestion was the approach I went with. Feel free to submit that as an answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 19):

Here is a solution by overriding the `sync` method, which I use to allow file uploads.

In this case I override the model's `sync` method, but this can also be the `Backbone.sync` method.

```
var FileModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  urlRoot: CMS_ADMIN_URL + '/config/files',

  sync: function(method, model, options){

    // Post data as FormData object on create to allow file upload
    if(method == 'create'){
      var formData = new FormData();

      // Loop over model attributes and append to formData
      _.each(model.attributes, function(value, key){
        formData.append(key, value);
      });

      // Set processData and contentType to false so data is sent as FormData
      _.defaults(options || (options = {}), {
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
      });
    }
    return Backbone.sync.call(this, method, model, options);
  }
});
```

**EDIT:**

To track upload progress, you can add a `xhr` option to options:

```
...

_.defaults(options || (options = {}), {
  data: formData,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false
  xhr: function(){
    // get the native XmlHttpRequest object
    var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
    // set the onprogress event handler
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
      if (event.lengthComputable) {
        console.log('%d%', (event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
        // Trigger progress event on model for view updates
        model.trigger('progress', (event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
      }
    };
    // set the onload event handler
    xhr.upload.onload = function(){
      console.log('complete');
      model.trigger('progress', 100);
    };
    // return the customized object
    return xhr;
  }
});

...
```

Comment: This is a good answer, IMO the best on this page.The proper way to handle server communication is to edit the sync method, here at the model level, but it does *not* require to extensively monkey-patch it: just edit the options hash (holding the data and xhr options), and you're done.

Answer (score 7):

Just to add an answer to this question, heres how I went about it without having to override the `sync`:

In my view, I have somethign like:

```
$('#' + $(e.currentTarget).data('fileTarget')).trigger('click').unbind('change').bind('change', function(){
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file', $(this)[0].files[0]);
    appManager.trigger('user:picture:change', form_data);
});
```

Which then triggers a function in a controller that does this:

```
var picture_entity = new appManager.Entities.ProfilePicture();
picture_entity.save(null, {
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
});
```

At that point, I'm overriding jQuery's `data` with my `FormData` object.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar requirement and here is what i did :

In View :

```
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#template_loader",
    initialize: function () {
        console.log('Home View Initialized');
    },
    render: function () {
        var inputData = {
            cId: cId,
            latitude: latitude,
            longitude: longitude
        };

        var data = new FormData();

        data.append('data', JSON.stringify(inputData));

        that.model.save(data, {
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (model, result) {
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. You can see above the way i solve it.

```
var $form = $("myFormSelector");

//==> GET MODEL FROM FORM
var model = new MyBackboneModel();
var myData = null;
var ajaxOptions = {};
// Check if it is a multipart request.
if ($form.hasFile()) {
    myData = new FormData($form[0]);
    ajaxOptions = {
        type: "POST",
        data: myData,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false
    };
} else {
    myData = $form.serializeObject();
}

// Save the model.
model.save(myData, $.extend({}, ajaxOptions, {
    success: function(model, data, response) {
        //==> INSERT SUCCESS
    },
    error: function(model, response) {
        //==> INSERT ERROR
    }
}));
```

The hasFile is a custom method that extends the JQuery functions.

```
$.fn.hasFile = function() {
    if ($.type(this) === "undefined")
        return false;

    var hasFile = false;
    $.each($(this).find(":file"), function(key, input) {
        if ($(input).val().length > 0) {
            hasFile = true;
        }
    });

    return hasFile;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Backbone.emulateJSON = true;`: http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateJSON

> will cause the JSON to be serialized under a model parameter, and the request to be made with a application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME type, as if from an HTML form.

Comment: But this serializes JSON to string, and get displayed as string like object.

Comment: It creates formData object and sends it to server

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked for me, below is simple and easy solution. By overriding `sync` method and `options.contentType` like this:

```
sync: function(method, model, options) {
    options = _.extend({
        contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
    }, options);

    options.data = jQuery.param(model.toJSON());

    return Backbone.sync.call(this, method, model, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple one will be, hope this will help someone.

1. Create a object of Backbone Model:

   ```
   var importModel = new ImportModel();
   ```
2. Call Save[POST] method of Backbone Model and Pass the FormData Object.

   ```
   var objFormData = new FormData();
   objFormData.append('userfile', files[0]);

   importModel.save(objFormData, {
    contentType: false, 
    data: objFormData, 
    processData: false,
    success: function(data, status, xhr) { },
    error: function(xhr, statusStr) { }
   });
   ```